# Segmentation fault with const string& constructor and templated std::set find

Tags: c++

The following code encountered a segment fault with the `const string&` constructor, and exit with 0 with the `string_view` constructor. I know the `const string&` is not the best way to do so. But from my understanding, without optimization, a temp `string` is constructed from `const char*`, then it's value gets copied in the `Person` constructor before it gets destroyed. And the constructor looks valid to me. For the find part, the `set::find (string_view)` will use the defined less operators as needed. And I didn't see what's wrong here. I am able to reproduce the issue with g++-10 or VS2022.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
using namespace std;

struct Person{
    string name;
    Person(const string& s):name{s}{}
    //Person(string_view s):name{s}{}
    bool operator<(string_view s)const{
        return name<s;
    }
    bool operator<(const Person& o)const{
        return name<o.name;
    }
};
bool operator<(string_view s,const Person& p){
    return s<p.name;
}
set<Person,less<>>s;

int main(){
    s.emplace("hello");
    string_view hel="hel";
    auto res=s.find(hel);
}
```

gdb gives me the following information about the crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000800280c in std::char_traits<char>::copy (__s1=0x7fffff7ef1c0 "\340\361~\377\377\177", __s2=0x7fffff7ef230 "hello",
    __n=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7eeff8>) at /usr/include/c++/10/bits/char_traits.h:401
401           copy(char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, size_t __n)
```

Comment: If you try to see the reason for the crash in the debugger, the problem appears to be quite obvious (hint: look at the call stack). Have you tried using your debugger? This is what it's there for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the suggestion, previously I only considered if the arguments look valid or not, when I do a `backtrace` it's obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your free-standing `operator<` calls itself recursively (and *infinitely*). This is because there is no in-built `<` operator that compares a `string_view` to a `string`, yet there *is* an implicit conversion from `string` to `const Person&`.

*Although there is also an implicit conversion from `string` to `string_view`, because there is an available conversion in the scope/namespace of the function itself, that is chosen over any other, found by argument-dependent lookup for the two operand types (thanks to Sam Varshavchik for pointing this out).*

So, in the body of that function, the right-hand operand of the `<` comparison is converted to a `const Person&`, and the function thus calls itself.

To fix the issue, convert the operands to the same STL type; either to 2 `string_view` operands, like this:

```cpp
bool operator<(string_view s, const Person& p)
{
    return s < string_view(p.name);
}
```

or to  2 `string` operands, like this:

```cpp
bool operator<(string_view s, const Person& p)
{
    return string(s) < p.name;
}
```

---

Note: This is not a particularly easy type of problem to spot. However, turning on (full) compiler warnings will likely help. For your original code, MSVC gives me this:

> warning C4717: 'operator<': recursive on all control paths, function
> will cause runtime stack overflow

And clang shows:

> warning : all paths through this function will call itself
> [-Winfinite-recursion]

Comment: wow, since it compiled, I didn't realize there wasn't a `<` operator for `string_view` and `string`

Comment: There's also an implicit conversion from `std::string` to a `std::string_view`. A complete answer would include why this implicit conversion was chosen.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thinking about it. Care to offer some help? :-) (It's very late where I am and way past the time I *should* be in the Land of Nod ... I'll sleep on it and *try* to offer a formal explanation.)

Comment: I believe that this is because implicit conversions in the current namespace are preferred over the ones found via argument-dependent lookups.

Comment: Thanks. I was working on the lines of ADL in the scope (namespace) of the function itself. I guess the function itself matches so there's is no further ADL.