# Overloading << and >> operators: The program compiles but running it doesn't accept input

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a `Fraction` class, which calculates the product of two fractions. It compiles fine but doesn't accept input and abruptly ends.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Fraction{
    int m_numerator{0},m_denominator{1};
    public:
    Fraction(int numerator=0,int denominator=1):m_numerator{numerator},m_denominator{denominator}{
    }
   
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1,const Fraction &f2);
    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f,int n);
    friend Fraction operator*(int n,const Fraction &f);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Fraction &f){
    out<<f.m_numerator<<'/'<<f.m_denominator;
    return out;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in,const Fraction &f);
};
istream &operator>>(istream &in,const Fraction &f){
    in>>f.m_numerator;
    in>>f.m_denominator;
    return in;
    }
Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f1,const Fraction &f2){
        return Fraction{f1.m_numerator*f2.m_numerator,f1.m_denominator*f2.m_denominator};
    }
Fraction operator*(const Fraction &f,int n){
    return Fraction(n*f.m_numerator,f.m_denominator);
}
Fraction operator*(int n,const Fraction &f){
    return Fraction(n*f.m_numerator,f.m_denominator);
}

int main(){
    Fraction f1;
    cin>>f1;

    Fraction f2;
    cin>>f2;

    std::cout << f1 << " * " << f2 << " is " << f1 * f2 << '\n'; 
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Are you inputting slashes, as in `1/2`? Your `operator>>` has no way of dealing with slashes.

Comment: FYI, [Clang warns for this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ovf1x5hGs). [So does MSVC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j9W5rcWbE).

Comment: @chris Similar issue on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69059828/10871073). IMHO, not sufficiently similar to call them duplicates, though.

Comment: No I am not able to input anything at all, after i run it it goes straight to the end.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your invocation command line and your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `const` qualifier on the second argument of your `operator>>`. First, this seems a bit weird, as you want to modify the values when they are given as input. Second, as there is no default overload for the `>>` operator that takes a `const int` operand, the best (*only?*) match for the internal `>>` operations is the function itself – and this causes infinite recursion.

To fix the issue, just remove that `const` qualifier:

```cpp
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& f)
{
    in >> f.m_numerator;
    in >> f.m_denominator;
    return in;
}
```

(And similarly, in the *declaration*.)

---

Note: To address the point made in the comments, about properly reading a fraction specified with a slash (i.e. input like `3/4`), you can simply add the following line between the two lines that read the numerator and denominator:

```cpp
    char slash;  in >> slash; // Skip the slash.
```

Comment: Side-Note: shouldn't you also consume a `/` when reading the fraction back?

Comment: @GPhilo I've added a footnote to address your (valid) point.

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted it to, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are running into an error is because you have an infinite recursion. Let's observe this snippet:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in,const Fraction &f){
  in>>f.m_numerator;
  in>>f.m_denominator;
  return in;
}
```

Here you have `istream >> int`, and since `Fraction` has a non-explicit constructor which can be initialized with f.m_numerator, you are effectivelly calling the same operator again. What you probably want is to call the operator `cin>>int`. So simplest way would be to just define the constructor as `explicit`. But this is only solution to the problem "why does it compile if it's wrong (or at least not what I wanted)?"

The other issue you have is the fact that you are trying to use `istream>>const int&`, since the fraction is passed by const reference, you aren't able to change the const (inherited) member (i.e. call the operator `istream>>int&`.

Comment: I see that your edit addresses the `const` issue. However, **just** adding `explicit` to the constructor gives this in MSVC: *error C2678: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)*.

Comment: I tried to describe the 2 issues separately, as on the first glance the behavior is "segfault because no suitable method was found?"

Comment: I understand. However, removing the `const` qualifier fixes the recursion issue. Calling `istream >> int` (without the `const`) isn't a problem. It resolves as it should.

Comment: Thank you! That worked exactly as I wanted it to.